# Find root of derivative of absolute value of complex number in sympy

Tags: python, sympy, symbolic-math

In essence what I want to do is take the absolute value of a complex number that has a parameter both in real and imaginary parts and derive that in respect to that parameter. I then want to know for which value of that parameter the derivative is zero. So essentially I want to know Min/Max of the absolute value of a complex number with parameters.

I've encountered a problem in using sympy and don't quite know how to fix it/if its a problem at their end. Before I report it as bug I wanted to ask here.
Ok so this is essentially what I want to do (the implementation is a bit more complex but the errors are the same)

```
0 import sympy
1 import mpmath
2 sympy.init_printing() # enable pretty printing
3 a,b = sympy.symbols("a,b") # a and b are symbols a and b
4 c = a+ 1j*b # complex number a+ib
5 d = sympy.Abs(c) # absolute value of c
6 e = d.diff(b,1) # derive d in respect to b one time
7 f = sympy.lambdify(b,e) # lambdify e with b as parameter
8 g = mpmath.findroot(f,0) # find root of f starting at 0
```

The error occurs in line 8 but because of `f`. Calling `f` with `f(1)` for example yields the same error. The error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1, in <lambda>
NameError: name 'Derivative' is not defined
```

I got the whole thing working but only if I wrote methods for stuff like the absolute value myself and avoided using the sympy functions. So for example

```
d = (sympy.re(c)**2 + sympy.im(c)**2)**0.5
```

worked fine but

```
d = sympy.sqrt(sympy.re(c)**2 + sympy.im(c)**2)
```

gave me an Error. That Error was essentially the same one as the one I describe next but with `Sqrt` in place of the `Add`.
It would be fine with me writing those methods myself but since the function is dynamically built at runtime(It's an electrical engineering toolbox) it's not a possibility to simply plug the stuff in; I have to rely on sympy.

I also got a Error that was something along the lines of:

```
Add doesn't contain Derivative Attribute.
```

which essentially meant that the complex number is an instance of the `Add` class of sympy and that doesn't have an differentiation method, but I can't get that to reproduce as of now.

Printing `e.subs(a,5).subs(b,1)` also shows that it doesn't substitute `a` and `b` inside the `Derivative()`.

Sorry that some things are a bit vague, I originally troubleshot the whole thing yesterday and forgot to save the code. If the whole thing is not an Error in Sympy but rather a mistake on my part I sincerly apologise and would love to get pointed in the direction of how it's done properly.

The whole thing is run under Anaconda 5.1.0 and debugged/managed in Visual Studio. In case you're interested in my exact implementation the project is hosted at https://github.com/SV-97/iphipy

The interesting files are Systems.py and Main.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what the lines 3-4 should have been

```
a, b = sympy.symbols("a, b", real=True) # a and b are REAL symbols a and b
c = a + I*b
```

By default, `a` and `b` are allowed to be complex numbers, which makes the computation of `Abs(a+I*b)` messy, and the differentiation of that with respect to `b` mathematically dubious.

Also, `1j` is a Python float, while `I` is a SymPy object; use the latter in symbolic expressions.

Now `e` will be computed as `b/sqrt(a**2 + b**2)`. But there is nothing that `mpmath.findroot` can do with this expression, given that it contains a *symbol* `a`, and `mpmath.findroot` is a *numeric* solver.

`sympy.solve(e, b)` does return an answer, `[0]`. Of course you may need a numeric solver in more complicated situations; but then make sure that everything except for the variable(s) being solved for has a numeric value.

Comment: Thanks, I actually searched for something like real=true because a mate recommended it but wasn't able to find something. As for the solver that was a mistake in the example here, in my actual implementation there's only one symbol